# Cannot parse lifecycle mapping metadata for maven project...Cause: Unrecognised tag: 'version'

Tags: maven, jenkins, jacoco

I am trying to get jacoco to work in the Jenkins build of a Maven project with four modules. It was working locally in eclipse when I ran the Maven build with `jacoco:prepare-agent test jacoco:report`. When I tried to add the goals to my Jenkins configuration, for one module the error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.9.1:ear (default-ear) on project *mymodule*: Cannot copy a directory: *myOthermodule*/target/classes; Did you package/install *myOthermodule*

appeared. My call in Jenkins is `clean package install -fae jacoco:prepare-agent test jacoco:report`. 
 So I tried to move the goal exeution from Jenkins to the pom and added

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

to the project's pom.xml. As a result the Error

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Plugin execution not covered
>   by lifecycle configuration:
>   org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:prepare-agent
>   (execution: default, phase: initialize)   pom.xml myproject   line 6  Maven
>   Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

appeared in all four modules (line 6 contains `<groupId>*myproject*</groupId>`).

Then I tried to add

```
   <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
```

to the project's pom.xml, and the error dissolved, but then the error

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>       Cannot parse lifecycle mapping metadata for maven project MavenProject: *myproject*:0.0.0-DEVELOPMENT @
>   *mypath*\pom.xml Cause: Unrecognised tag: 'version' (position: START_TAG seen ...\r\n        ...)
>     pom.xml /*mymodule* line 1  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping
>   Problem

appeared in all modules. Line 1 is

`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">`

I checked that I used the version tags correctly (not using a range with a version tag or vice versa)

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Tag `versionRange` should be used in `pluginExecutionFilter` instead of `version` - https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html

Comment: Thanks alot! I did not think that could be the problem, and since I need this specisif version, I did not consider using versionRange. I used `<versionRange>(,0.7.4.201502262128]</versionRange>` and that solved the issue.